# Panel Color custom in FLASH CS6

Tags: image, flash, flash-cs6, uiloader

I have a Flash file.
I'm working on this demo project where I want to customize the color of the panels according to the thumbnails when clicked on them.
The colors of the front floor must change accordingly to the color mentioned and same goes for the front wall.

I have uploaded the .FLA file [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?2ljw8l8q0xjdit4)
The SWF file is [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?y21f1w2jz1t24t4) 
Can anyone please help me out on this query on how i can implement it the simplest way possible without the use of Cold Fusion?

Comment: Please post the actual code here so we can help you out. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something very simple with GreenSock´s TweenMax.

Something like:

```
import com.greensock.TweenMax;

mybutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, change_red);

function change_red(e:MouseEvent):void{    
TweenMax.to{panel_a, 1,{tint:0xff0000});
}
```

There are many other ways to achieve your goal, but I think this is the easiest way.

For further information about TweenMax take a look to [the GreenSock website](http://www.greensock.com/)

Good luck!